# sonarqube analysis requires authentication when permission is anyone

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

sonarqube 5.5 
several Java projects, all have permission set to anyone can execute analysis.
use mvn sonar:sonar to run analysis 
Other projects work fine without error.
One project was found to not have the permission set. It was giving:

> Not authorized. Analyzing this project requires to be authenticated.
>   Please provide the values of the properties sonar.login and
>   sonar.password.

Setting the permission does not fix it.  This project continues to give this error.

Steps taken:

- Permission is being set on the Project Permissions page, adding Anyone group to EXECUTE ANALYSIS permission.  Users 0, groups 1
- toggle permission off then on again.
- restart server.
- remove local sonar/cache

There are two projects with the same name but different keys.  QA version and Release.

Not sure what to try next.

---

------ short log --- mvn -X follows

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar (default-cli) @ adminportal-api ---
[INFO] User cache: /Users/kenhargreaves/.sonar/cache
[INFO] Load global repositories
[INFO] Load global repositories (done) | time=265ms
[INFO] User cache: /Users/kenhargreaves/.sonar/cache
[INFO] Exclude plugins: devcockpit, buildstability, pdfreport, report, scmstats, buildbreaker, views, jira
[INFO] Load plugins index
[INFO] Load plugins index (done) | time=16ms
[INFO] SonarQube version: 5.5
[INFO] Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
[INFO] -- Cache for project [com.fusemail:adminportal-api] not found, synchronizing data..
[INFO] Load rules
[INFO] Load rules (done) | time=244ms
[INFO] Load project settings
[INFO] Load project settings (done) | time=182ms
[INFO] Load project quality profiles
[INFO] Load project quality profiles (done) | time=59ms
[INFO] Load project active rules
[INFO] Load project active rules (done) | time=888ms
[INFO] Load server issues
[INFO] Load server issues (done) | time=844ms
[INFO] Load user information
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.221 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-22T11:39:38-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 65M/470M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar (default-cli) on project adminportal-api: Not authorized. Analyzing this project requires to be authenticated. Please provide the values of the properties sonar.login and sonar.password. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 

-----------------
INFO] Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
[DEBUG] Work directory: /Users/kenhargreaves/Documents/workspace/fm-api-portalapi/target/sonar
[DEBUG] Execution getVersion
[DEBUG] Execution execute
[DEBUG] cache: /Users/kenhargreaves/.sonar/ws_cache/http%3A%2F%2Fsonarqube.electric.net/5.5/projects/com.fusemail%3Aadminportal-api
[INFO] -- Cache for project [com.fusemail:adminportal-api] not found, synchronizing data..
[INFO] Load rules
[DEBUG] GET 200 http://sonarqube.electric.net/api/rules/list.protobuf | time=100ms
[INFO] Load rules (done) | time=176ms
[INFO] Load project settings
[DEBUG] GET 200 http://sonarqube.electric.net/batch/project.protobuf?key=com.fusemail%3Aadminportal-api&issues_mode=true | time=53ms
[INFO] Load project settings (done) | time=158ms
[INFO] Load project quality profiles
[DEBUG] GET 200 http://sonarqube.electric.net/api/qualityprofiles/search.protobuf?projectKey=com.fusemail%3Aadminportal-api | time=41ms
[INFO] Load project quality profiles (done) | time=53ms
[INFO] Load project active rules
[DEBUG] GET 200 http://sonarqube.electric.net/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives&activation=true&qprofile=c-sonar-way-50322&p=1&ps=500 | time=128ms
[DEBUG] GET 200 http://sonarqube.electric.net/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives&activation=true&qprofile=cpp-sonar-way-23842&p=1&ps=500 | time=160ms
[DEBUG] GET 200 http://sonarqube.electric.net/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives&activation=true&qprofile=java-sonar-03590&p=1&ps=500 | time=64ms
[DEBUG] GET 200 http://sonarqube.electric.net/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives&activation=true&qprofile=js-sonar-way-84357&p=1&ps=500 | time=103ms
[DEBUG] GET 200 http://sonarqube.electric.net/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives&activation=true&qprofile=objc-sonar-way-52782&p=1&ps=500 | time=123ms
[DEBUG] GET 200 http://sonarqube.electric.net/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives&activation=true&qprofile=py-sonar-way-75611&p=1&ps=500 | time=69ms
[INFO] Load project active rules (done) | time=728ms
[INFO] Load server issues
[DEBUG] GET 200 http://sonarqube.electric.net/batch/issues.protobuf?key=com.fusemail%3Aadminportal-api | time=333ms
[INFO] Load server issues (done) | time=524ms
[INFO] Load user information
[DEBUG] GET 401 http://sonarqube.electric.net/batch/users?logins=axxx.mxxxx | time=31ms
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.647 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-22T11:42:01-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 66M/467M
```

The user we see there did have an account in the sonarqube server, I did remove him to see what happens.

Comment: Can you please paste the full log please? I need to see exactly where this fails.

Comment: Moreover do you use the property sonar.branch or are the initial keys different ?

Comment: Not using sonar.branch.  the keys for the two projects are different.

Answer (score 44):

Go to SonarQube web page, administration, and then go to security and disable "Force User Authentication".

Comment: I downvoted this comment but it turned out to be a perfect solution to the problem.  I'm only ever running the scan locally so no security issue to worry about!  Sorry for the downvote!

Comment: You are a savior! I am also trying to run a local sonar scan with Jacoco and was getting auth error even though I set token in sonar properties. Turns out, as you mentioned, we have to disable this check in Security tab. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am testing SonarQube enterprise edition - do not see that option `Force User Authentication` under Security

Comment: @Sasha Bond -  I found it under Administration -> Configuration -> Security

Comment: now, no authentication will be required for the SonarQube server, anyone can play! :(

Answer (score 19):

Are you forcing authentication in SonarQube?

If this is the case, you basically need to:

1. Generate a token for the user-account in SonarQube
2. Expose the token in an environment variable, say `SONAR_TOKEN` as below:
   `export SONAR_TOKEN="<your_token>"` (bash/GitBash)
   `SET SONAR_TOKEN="<your_token>"` (bat/Windows)
3. Use the token in you maven command like:
   `mvn ... sonar:sonar -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_TOKEN` (bash/GitBash)
   `mvn ... sonar:sonar -Dsonar.login=%SONAR_TOKEN%` (bat/Windows)

This is extensively discussed at [Sonarqube authorization - how to authorize with sonar-maven-plugin when sonar.forceAuthentication is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46114028/sonarqube-authorization-how-to-authorize-with-sonar-maven-plugin-when-sonar-fo).

Comment: From my point of view, this should be the selected answer. This is working, and you don't need to add your password in clear.

Answer (score 5):

While trying sonar-scanner with the latest sonerQube I got the following error

> ERROR: Not authorized. Analyzing this project requires to be
> authenticated. Please provide the values of the properties sonar.login
> and sonar.password.

The solution to this is to add sonar.login and sonar.password properties in the **Project root configuration file**. You can find its path during run of your sonar-scanner

> INFO: Scanner configuration file:
> /Users//.sonar/native-sonar-scanner/sonar-scanner-4.4.0.2170-macosx/conf/sonar-scanner.properties

Update this file with following properties
sonar.login=
sonar.password=

Try again, you should get your issue resolved.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried multiple solutions to fix this issue, but the one that works fine for me is to run this command: mvn verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.login=admin -Dsonar.password=YOUR_PASSWORD

**Note: No need to disable 'Force user authentication' or change the permissions.

Answer (score 3):

If you are getting this error with the new version of sonarqube.

You need to follow below steps.

1. Go to **Administration**.
2. Then click on **Configuration**.
3. Go to **Security**.
4. Scroll down to the end and click on **Force user authentication**.

Now disable it and click on save.

You will not be getting this error any more now.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and could fix it

moving the SonarQube configuration from module `build.gradle` to app `build.gradle`.

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.host.url", System.getenv("SONAR_URL_KEY")
        property "sonar.login", System.getenv("SONAR_LOGIN_KEY")
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy:
First go to to http://localhost:9000/admin/settings?category=security. After that, you should see a checkpoint that say `Force user authentication`, unclick it and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

1.Force user authentication

2.Create a configuration file in your project's root directory called sonar-project.properties

```
# must be unique in a given SonarQube instance
sonar.projectKey=my:project

# --- optional properties ---

# defaults to project key
#sonar.projectName=My project
# defaults to 'not provided'
#sonar.projectVersion=1.0
 
# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Defaults to .
#sonar.sources=.
 
# Encoding of the source code. Default is default system encoding
#sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```