# Sonarqube authorization - how to authorize with sonar-maven-plugin when sonar.forceAuthentication is enabled

Tags: sonarqube, authorization, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan, runner

I've got sonarqube 6.5 with default configs. When sonar.forceAuthentication flag is set to false, I can create and analyse project through command given below.

`mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=https://mySonarHost/sonar -Dsonar.login=mySonarUserKey`

When I enable sonar.forceAuthentication parameter (sonar.forceAuthentication=true), I can't analyse project. I always get maven error:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project storm: Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password. -> [Help 1]`

It doesn't work on default admin account nor created user account (with permission to analyse project). I've also tried not to use user key, but user' login and password (`-Dsonar.login` and `-Dsonar.password` in maven config) but it also doesn't work.
I've tried to use different sonar version (from 4.5.7, through 5.6.6 to the newest, 6.5, but I always get the same result).

During the connection, I've got such messages in my access.log:

```
IP_ADDRESS - - [08/Sep/2017:12:03:33 +0200] "GET /sonar/batch/index HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "ScannerMaven/3.3.0.603/3.5.0" "SOME_KEY"
IP_ADDRESS - - [08/Sep/2017:12:03:33 +0200] "GET /sonar/api/settings/values.protobuf HTTP/1.1" 401 - "-" "ScannerMaven/3.3.0.603/3.5.0" "SOME_KEY"
```

It's required for me to set sonar.forceAuthentication parameter to true (only trusted users can have access to it).

Any idea how to configure and access sonarqube through maven with credential parameters?

Comment: If login / password didn't work, you might have an authenticating reverse proxy in front.  I did and it failed.  When I removed it, it worked. That said, I've not gotten then token to ever work from maven. Did you? My question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48347351/sonarqube-token-access-when-ldap-is-enabled

Answer (score 16):

Did you set both `sonar.login` and `sonar.password` parameters ([Analyzing with SonarQube Scanner for Maven (Archive)](https://web.archive.org/web/20161127125444/http://docs.sonarqube.org:80/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven)) ?

Note that in recent versions (like SonarQube 6.5), you should use a user token and just set it in the `sonar.login` parameter: [User Token](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/user-token/)

Answer (score 10):

This is a minimal command that I use to update Sonar Cube Dashboard for my project,

```
mvn clean install  sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=<Server_URL> -Dsonar.login=<Token_For_Your_User_Id> -Dsonar.projectKey=<It will be calculated by default using group id & artifact id but its advisable that you use a unique string for all users> -Dsonar.projectName=<Descriptive Project Name to show on dashboard> -Dsonar.projectVersion=<if you wish to specify a version number>
```

You can always wrap a string value in double quotes if it has spaces in it.

Before using above command, you need to generate token for your user id as specified in answer provided by Eric. There is no need to pass password property.

Answer (score 1):

I added a single space after -D and all was well with the world!

Comment: I would be very surprised if adding a space there would work considering `-D<myProperty>=some-value` is the standard and accepted way of passing system properties to the JVM

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of simplicity and clarity, here's how to add just your sonar credentials to the mvn command:

```
mvn verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.login=admin -Dsonar.password=password
```