# SonarQube token access when LDAP is enabled

Tags: maven, ldap, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Just stood up a brand new SonarQube **6.7.1** server and configured it to authenticate users via the LDAP plugin (**2.2 build 608**). So far so good.

However, when users trying to run a command line scan using maven with a token:

`mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.login=438fd33be6d6e5c9146c674717fea4675f0eb`

...they get the following error:

`Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password.`

The Sonar logs are showing:

`2018.01.19 18:20:14 DEBUG web[AWELLmgpg7dbJTF2AALW][o.s.p.l.LdapUsersProvider] User 438fd33be6d6e5c9146c674717fea4675f0eb not found in &lt;default&gt;
2018.01.19 18:20:14 DEBUG web[AWELLmgpg7dbJTF2AALW][auth.event] login failure [cause|No user details][method|BASIC][provider|REALM|LDAP]`

This makes it look like Sonar's LDAP plugin is attempting to look up a user on LDAP whose name would be the access token.  Clearly this isn't going to work!

We are using sonar maven plugin version **3.4.0.905**.

**Edit: The same token works from IntelliJ SonarLint.  Which seems to point to the Maven plugin being at fault here.**

Comment: Are you sure that users didn't add `sonar.password` parameter with any value?

Comment: That's a good guess, but no, the password parameter was empty

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct token value? Maybe a character got dropped off the end? Or were you able to use this token successfully before you enabled LDAP auth? Also, please [edit] your question to include some version numbers: SQ, LDAP plugin, [anything else relevant-seeming].

Comment: I added the version numbers for everything.  I doubled checked the token value, and it was correct.  I also verified that the token works from SonarLint.  This is a brand new server so we have no history here...

Comment: Please execute `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression="sonar.login"` and `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression="sonar.password"`. Off course add also all parameters which you are appended to `mvn sonar:sonar`.

Comment: @agabrys - thank you for the suggestion!!! It turns out the password value as not empty, it was **admin**.   It must be a Maven default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @agabrys for the tip.

Running this Maven command:

```
mvn clean verify help:evaluate -Dexpression="sonar.password" -Dsonar.login=438fd33be6d6e5c9146c674717fea4675f0eb
```

Returned:

```
admin
```

In order to accept the token, then password must be empty.  It must be the Maven sonar plugin that is setting this default password!!  Setting the default password to empty via this:

```
mvn clean verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.password= -Dsonar.login=438fd33be6d6e5c9146c674717fea4675f0eb
```

Worked.

Comment: `mvn clean verify help:evaluate -Dexpression="sonar.password" -Dsonar.login=438fd33be6d6e5c9146c674717fea4675f0eb` command doesn't execute sonar-maven-plugin, so password cannot be set by it. If `pom.xml` files don't contain `sonar.password` then it must be hardcoded in `settings.xml`.

Comment: I realize it is not the help plug-in that is setting the password it is the maven sonar plug-in itself that is setting the password. I have not said that password in any file we have here

Comment: The docs for sonarqube https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/User+Token say that sonar.password is "optional" - clearly this is a lie.

Comment: Wasted a full day on this and including -Dsonar.password= (with no password) along with -Dsonar.login=<MY_TOKEN_ID> finally worked!

Answer (score 0):

If it still refuses to work after adding the empty password option, try adding a space after -D