# SonarQube Not authorized. Spring Boot Gradle Project

Tags: spring-boot, sonarqube

I have a spring boot Gradle project. I am implementing sonarqube. For that I added sonar-project.properties file .

```
sonar.projectKey=springboiperplate
sonar.projectName=springboiperplate
sonar.projectVersion=1.0.0
sonar.host.url = http://localhost:9000
sonar.login = admin
sonar.password = 1234
sonar.dynamicAnalysis = reuseReports
sonar.junit.reportsPath = build/test-reports
sonar.java.coveragePlugin = jacoco
sonar.jacoco.reportPath = build/test-reports/jacoco.exec


#MySQL
sonar.jdbc.url =jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springboot_boilerplate?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
sonar.jdbc.username = root
sonar.jdbc.password = 1234
```

wwhen I run .\gradlew sonarqube

this command its shows
Not authorized. Analyzing this project requires authentication. Please provide a user token in sonar.login or other credentials in sonar.login and sonar.password.
this above error.

Comment: did you try following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488996/sonarqube-analysis-requires-authentication-when-permission-is-anyone . Maybe there is an issue with the project permissions